# In an Electron Application I am successfully making an HTTP GET request from an Angular component. How can I do the same thing from the Electron side?

Tags: angular, http, electron

The following function is working from an Angular component in my Electron app:

```
getData() {


    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1';
    this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise()
    .then(response=> {
        //...
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
  }
```

The alert prints out the same text as you will see if you browse to https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1

i.e.:

```
{"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}
```

Now, I've tried several methods to get this to work from the Electron main app side.

Here is my current incarnation (it's in the app.on function of my main.ts):

```
const { net } = require('electron')
  const request = net.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1'})
  request.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
  })
  request.end()
```

It all runs without error and I have response.statusCode = 200.

But where in the response can I find the JSON data returned from https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1 ?

I thought it might be in the 'chunk' variable, well if I stringify it I have:

'{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,112,97,103,101,34,58,49,44,34,112,101,114,95,112,97,103,101,34,58,54,44,34,116,111,116,97,108,34,58,49,50,44,34,116,111,116,97,108,95,112,97,103,101,115,34,58,50,44,34,100,97,116,97,34,58,91,123,34,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,101,109,97,105,108,34,58,34,103,101,111,114,103,101,46,98,108,117,116,104,64,114,101,113,114,101,115,46,105,110,34,44,34,102,105,114,115,116,95,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,71,101,111,114,103,101,34,44,34,108,97,115,116,95,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,66,1…117,112,112,111,114,116,34,58,123,34,117,114,108,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,114,101,113,114,101,115,46,105,110,47,35,115,117,112,112,111,114,116,45,104,101,97,100,105,110,103,34,44,34,116,101,120,116,34,58,34,84,111,32,107,101,101,112,32,82,101,113,82,101,115,32,102,114,101,101,44,32,99,111,110,116,114,105,98,117,116,105,111,110,115,32,116,111,119,97,114,100,115,32,115,101,114,118,101,114,32,99,111,115,116,115,32,97,114,101,32,97,112,112,114,101,99,105,97,116,101,100,33,34,125,125]}'

Is this it in binary form? If so how would I convert it?

Or should I be looking at an entirely different approach from using net.request?

Or indeed, can I use HttpClient from the electron apps main.ts just as I do in the Angular component?

I ask becasue in the Angular component I introduce it via the constructor like so:

```
constructor(
              private http:HttpClient,) {
    super();
```

but there is no constructor in the main.ts of the Electron app.

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
response.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
})
```

`chunk` is a Buffer of part of the response body data. In order to get the full response body as JSON, you would need to concatenate all buffers and then parse it as JSON. i.e.

```
let buffers = [];

response.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(`Buffer: ${chunk}`);
  buffers.push(chunk);
})

response.on('end', () => {
  let responseBodyBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
  let responseBodyJSON = JSON.parse(responseBodyBuffer.toString());
  console.log(`BODY: ${responseBodyJSON}`);
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. It works. Am very grateful for that. Would you\anyone know how I could add header info in to the Electron side GET call? On the Angular component side I did the following: let header = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": 'application/json', "Authorization": myToken});

    const requestOptions = {headers: header};   and then I called   this.http.get<any>(url, requestOptions)         Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually I should post this as a new question because the main question has been answered and the comment space is not big enough to let me clearly lay out this corollary question. Thanks.

Comment: @user3738290 this is the method you're looking for https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/client-request#requestsetheadername-value. So it would be request.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json')